# Getting Error while running program

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
try:
    import sys
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    import sys
    from urllib2 import urlopen

def fetch_words(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    print(html.read())
    story_words = []
    for line in html:
        line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
    for word in line_words:
        story_words.append(word)
    return story_words


def print_items(items):
    for item in items:
        print(item)


def main():
    url = sys.argv[1]
    words = fetch_words(url)
    print_items(words)

if name == '__main__'
    main()
```

Comment: You need to edit the formatting of your question as code.

Answer (score 0):

You might have other errors, but surely, `name` is not declared, so

```
if name == 'main'
```

will raise you an error. Instead, it should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

Comment: Can u try that code once and tell me what is that error

Comment: @chichu Are you the riddler? Am I supposed to run this bunch of plain text as a Python code, so I can find out what error you get?